# Plotly: Plot a time series with relative times

Tags: javascript, plotly, scatter-plot, plotly.js

I want to use Plotly.js to visualize a time series with relative times (in ms) between different events. As an example I have the following data:

```
[
{"group": 0, "event": "A", "relativeTime": 0},
{"group": 0, "event": "B", "relativeTime": 1000},
{"group": 0, "event": "C", "relativeTime": 2000},
{"group": 1, "event": "A", "relativeTime": 0},
{"group": 1, "event": "B", "relativeTime": 5000},
{"group": 1, "event": "C", "relativeTime": 10000},
{"group": 2, "event": "A", "relativeTime": 0},
{"group": 2, "event": "B", "relativeTime": 30000}
{"group": 2, "event": "C", "relativeTime": 300000},
]
```

The data presents different *groups* (in the example group 0-2), each group has several *events* (event A-C), and a *relative time span* between the first event of a group and the current event in milliseconds. For instance: {"group": 0, "event": "B", "relativeTime": 1000} means that event "B" of group "0" is 1000ms away from event "A" of group "0".

To draw the graph I use a scatter plot, with the *groups* for the y-Axis, the *relativeTimes* for the x-Axis, and the *events* for the coloring. When I draw this data in a scatter plot, I get something like this:
[image]

Moreover, I would like to offer the possibility to zoom. When zoomed, the graph looks, for instance, like this:
[image]

The screenshots show my current status.

**Now my problem is the following:**
As you can see in the screenshots the x-Axis shows the milliseconds. However, for better readability, I would like to show this in months, days, hours, or maybe minutes depending on the zoom level. For instance, if the graph is not zoomed the graph should show the times in days (e.g., 1d, 2d, 3d, ...) and if the graph is zoomed the times should be shown in minutes (e.g., 10min, 20min, 30min, ...). Is there a way to do that?